# MySQL. Блокировка строк

Tags: mysql, innodb

Всем привет!
Есть таблица, содержащая 2 миллиона записей. Каждый раз показывает 50 новый записей. Сейчас sql выглядит таким образом(к сожаление нельзя исправить, т.к. генерируется CRM-кой): `SELECT * FROM table order by ID LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0`.

Видно узкое место - мы вначале вытаскиваем все записи,сортируем их, а потом только берем 50. Худо-бедно запрос отрабатывает.

А теперь вопрос: каждый определенный интервал времени мы обновляем последовательно каждую запись. И пока происходит обновление - мы не можем выполнить наш главный запрос на отображение последних 50 строк. Как сделать так, что бы и обновление и выборка работали не конфликтуя?
Дабы усложнить задачу - при выборке 50 записей мы join-ним пару таблиц.

Пробовал использовать HIGH/LOW_PRIORITY - не помогает.

Подсистема хранения - InnoDB.

Comment: Это почему же не можете выполнить запрос? Выборка останавливается в ожидании завершения обновления или вылетает с ошибкой? Или записей не хватает? В чём проблема-то?

Comment: Проблем в том, что время выполнения и получения запроса превышает предельное значение и сервер возвращает 500 ошибку.

Comment: Увеличьте предельное время. Можете же посмотреть как долго выполняется запрос. Как устроено ваше приложение. Дожидается результат и выгружает страничку? Переделайте чтобы работало с долгими запросами (есть для этого разные техники, чтобы клиент был чем-то занят на время выполнения)

Comment: Почему он у вас долго работает тоже не ясно. Вот пишите в заголовке "блокировка". Если в самом деле зависает на мёртвой блокировке - это одно. А если просто не терпится дождаться, когда он закончит, не зная что там на самом деле - это немого другое.

Comment: @banme Решил проблему. Каждый раз при построении списка брались все записи, сортировались и выбирались первые N строк. и если во время первичной выборки происходит вставка - мы не можем выбрать. Вам +1 за совет